# SSRS Report headers does not display

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a strange thing, when running an ssrs report it does not display the headings text when viewing the report in the web browser, but when you export that same report to excel or pdf the heading text is visible.

The same report runs on my local test environment normally.

I have tried setting the resolution of the PC, Zoom in and Out of the report.

I really am at a loss here.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Are you using the same browser? Not all SSRS features work with all browsers.

Comment: Are we talking about the header (as in the question title) or headings (like titles on the report itself)?

Comment: Headings of the report itself. It shows the borders of the headings but the text is not displayed

Comment: Have you checked the ccs isn't overwriting it?

Comment: Can you show the headings in design mode and when the report is run? You didn't set the text color the same as the background? I know, stupid question..